# How does one calculate $\pi_1 (S^2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have managed to try to convince myself that I can show  $\pi_1 (S^1)$~$\mathbb{Z}$

The recipe I am going by is something like this

i) Find a covering map $p$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^1$

ii) Let f be a loop on $S^1$

iii) One is interested in the lifting to tease things out

It seems the idea is that one can probably use $p(x) = (\cos(2 \pi x ), \sin(2 \pi x)
)$ and $f(x) = (\cos(2 \pi n x ), \sin(2 \pi n x))$

Then the lifting is gotten by matching from  $p \circ \tilde{f} = f$

$\tilde{f} = x n$

So one sees the integers coming out of this since one has a loop.

Can one generalize this sort of thinking to $S^2$? How does one obtain $\pi_1 {S^2}$

I am guessing that one can construct $p$ to be something like $(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), cos(\theta))$

For the loops, I am not quite sure how to do that.  They should be generally circles on a sphere, and then one seeks to compute the lifting and hopefully at the end make an identification with {0}.

I am not sure if this can be done, or if this will work.

Comment: Computing $\pi_1(S^1)$ is "easy" because it has a contractible covering space. The only (connected) space that covers $S^2$ is $S^2$ itself so this strategy does not reduce the difficulty at all.

Comment: There are many ways to calculate $\pi_1(S^2)$, the standard one is through [Seifert-Van Kampen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem).

Comment: One can also use cellular approximation.

Comment: @freakish I have now looked at the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem. It seems what one does is look at the sphere as two hemispheres with an intersection(small overlap) at the equator and then notice that one can compute the $\pi_1$ separately and then recombine by a rule. Basically one computes for two discs coming from the hemispheres and then the intersection is a circle.  I am not yet completely clear on how to take the "free product", but it would seem this is literally an alternating product. This last part of the free product is the last bit I think I need to iron out.

Comment: @KevinNjokom to be precise Seifert-Van Kampen talks about free product with amalgamation. But you don't have to worry about that in this particular case, because $\pi_1$ of a hemisphere is trivial (since hemisphere is contractible). All you need to know is that free product (with amalgamation or not) of two trivial groups is trivial. And this generalizes to any sphere of dimension $2$ or higher.